# Scala implicit conversion to add methods to Int

Tags: primes, scala, integer, extension-methods, trait

I started learning Scala, and like most functional languages, things get messy pretty quickly for a beginner.

Here I have built a wrapper class for `Int`s so that I can declare additional functions for the Int class. For example, I want to be able to do something like `1.isPrime`, and it should call a function that tells me if the given number is prime or not.

Here is my code:

```
package object Arithmetic {
    trait S99Int { me =>
        var value: Int = 0
        implicit def int2S99Int(value: Int):me.type = {
            me.value = value; me
        }
    }
}
```

The above creates the implicit conversions that enable any class that conforms to the trait, to be able to declare additional functions for `Int`s. For example, I can now do this:

```
import Arithmetic._

object S99IntPrime extends S99Int {
    import scala.math.{sqrt, abs}

    def isPrime: Boolean = value match {
        case -1|0|1 => false
        case p      => Stream.cons(2,
        Stream.range(3, sqrt(abs(p)).toInt + 1, 2)) forall (p % _ != 0)
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { 
        println(args.head.toInt.isPrime)
    }
}
```

I am mostly asking this question about the first snippet I posted. What are the advantages/disadvantages with declaring the base object like I have? Recommendations? Warnings? I just started learning Scala, so any advice will save me hours of Googling.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what Scala version are you using? If you're using `2.10` or newer versions, the language has introduced [`implicit classes`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html) which help you avoid the definition of implicit conversions - as a side note implicit classes are translated to implicit conversions by the compiler so let's say they are some type of syntactic sugar.

As you might now, the `implicit` modifier cannot be used on top-level definitions - that includes implicit classes as well, so we must wrap them in a class / trait / object. As a best practice it's best to put them in an object (or package object like you did). The other constraints of implicit classes are already explained in the first link, so I won't go through them here.

A final note before we get to the code is that you will often see that implicit classes are used as [`value classes`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html). Please consult [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929422/should-implicit-classes-always-extend-anyval) if you're curious to see how when you should mix them with value classes.

Enough talk, let's see the code now:

```scala
package object arithmetic {
  implicit class RichInt(val value: Int) extends AnyVal {
    def isPrime: Boolean = ???
  }
}

object ArithmeticTest extends App {
  import arithmetic._
  1.isPrime
}
```

That's it! Hope it helps.